# Hint in Search Widget within Action Bar is not showing up

Tags: java, android, colors, android-actionbar, hint

I have a  Search Widget within an Action Bar. I have set up an android:hint value however It is not showing up when I click on the Search Icon.

Relevant Files :

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.myApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //creates an action bar. 
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //sets the homebutton. 
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
  }   
}
```

Main.xml => res/menu/Main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"       
          />
</menu>
```

searchable.xml => res/XML/searchable.XMl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="search"
        android:textColorHint= "#FF0000"      
    />
```

Mainfest.XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MyApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyApp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

             <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My attempt :

My action-bar has a black background so I assumed that I initially could not see the :hint value as the hint text color is black is as well. However even after changing the hintTextColor, I still can not see the hint value.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For some reason you need to put `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>` inside your  tag. That's what fixed the problem for me.
But be careful to put it in this order

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

otherwise your activity won't be recognized as launcher

Comment: This works because the documentation say it's needed, look at this link https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/search/setup.html#create-sa

Answer (score 17):

No one has been able to answer my question yet...

I have found a way to change the hint value in the .java file but not in the **.xml** file.

Within the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method of `MainActivity.java`, I can do:

```
searchView.setQueryHint("HINT TEXT...");
```

I believe I should still be able to preset a hint value of a SearchWidget in XML just like a simple `EditText`.

Comment: It would appear this is a bug in Android. See my answer below for an explanation + solution.

Answer (score 14):

Your have to provide a string resource for the hint attribute. Hardcoded text won't work. Instead of

```
android:hint="search"
```

use a string resource

```
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
```

The doc is clear about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

```
android:hint="string resource"
```

Comment: I... don't understand why this is enforced, but thanks for an awesome tip!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. There has to be something more to it.

Comment: For some reason you must use search_hint resource. You cannot use another resource name.
Like this: android:hint="@string/search_hint"

Answer (score 14):

**If you want to skip to the solution, just scroll down**

### Explanation

It appears this would be a bug in `SearchView`.

Edit: I reported this bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174273).
Edit 2 : seems to be fixed for a future release, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169840&can=1&q=searchableinfo&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

In the constructor, it assigns a value to the field `mQueryHint`.

```
public SearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    ...
    final CharSequence queryHint = a.getText(R.styleable.SearchView_queryHint);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(queryHint)) {
        setQueryHint(queryHint);
    }
    ...
}

public void setQueryHint(CharSequence hint) {
    mQueryHint = hint;
    updateQueryHint();
}
```

Later, when you set the `SearchableInfo` (you know, the object it should read the hint from), the following happens:

```
public void setSearchableInfo(SearchableInfo searchable) {
    mSearchable = searchable;
    if (mSearchable != null) {
        ...
        updateQueryHint();
    }
    ...
}
```

All seems ok until now. It saves the `searchableInfo` in a field called `mSearchable`. Let's see what `updateQueryHint` does:

```
private void updateQueryHint() {
    if (mQueryHint != null) {
        mSearchSrcTextView.setHint(getDecoratedHint(mQueryHint));
    } else if (IS_AT_LEAST_FROYO && mSearchable != null) {
        CharSequence hint = null;
        int hintId = mSearchable.getHintId();
        if (hintId != 0) {
            hint = getContext().getString(hintId);
        }
        if (hint != null) {
            mSearchSrcTextView.setHint(getDecoratedHint(hint));
        }
    } else {
        mSearchSrcTextView.setHint(getDecoratedHint(""));
    }
}
```

What? So if `mQueryHint` already has a value, we never even read the searchable info? That explains why we never see our hint, because `mQueryHint` is assigned to a default value in the SearchView constructor (see above).

### Solution

So how do we work around this bug?

Two options:

1. Use setQueryHint with the new value.

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);

    // Override the hint with whatever you like
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.strings.your_hint));

    return true;
}
```

2. Use setQueryHint with null BEFORE you set the SearchableInfo

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

    // DO THIS BEFORE setSearchableInfo !!!
    searchView.setQueryHint(null);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);

    return true;
}
```

Both confirmed working with appcompat v7.

Comment: Calling searchView.setQueryHint(null) worked for me with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

Comment: I wish all SO answers were explained this thoroughly. Great job!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
android:queryHint="Hint text"
```

in your Search Widget in XML.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer does indeed work, but only for the MAIN activity. If you would want to use it in another activity it would not work.

The below code  is taken from [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

</activity>
```